# JavaScript: Trim Whitespaces From An Object's Keys Both From Left and Right

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this object with a lot of white spaces from the server side and I would like to remove both left and right spaces from its keys. Object results look like below:

```
{0: "          customer-registered", 1:"      customer not registered                     " 2: "       customer-registered    "}
```

How can I remove left and right white spaces and restructure the object to look like:

```
{0: "customer-registered", 1:"customer not registered" 2: "customer-registered"}
```

Comment: You can't trim whitespace from an object; that makes no sense. You can however trim whitespace from string property values in the object.

Comment: Are you sure that is not an array of strings ?

Comment: @pointy I have edited the title to mention Object's keys instead...

Comment: Those aren't keys, they are values.

Answer (score 3):

You can trim the string-valued properties:

```
Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(key => yourObject[key] = yourObject[key].trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointy's answer does in place modification. If you don't want that, you can use reduce

```
Object.keys(obj).reduce((accu, key) => {accu[key] = obj[key].trim(); return accu;}, {})
```

Depends on your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Have solved it with the following:

```
let customerObj =  Object.keys(yourObject).map(k => yourObject[k] = 
yourObject[k].trim());

console.log('customerObj Results: ', customerObj);
```